# How to list all .mp3 files in my android device in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to develop a music player application in Xamarin.Forms. I want to play songs in Music folder of my android device. How I can get all .mp3 files?

It is my Song model.

```
namespace MusicPlayer.Models
 {
  public class Song
   {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string AlbumImageUri { get; set; }
    public object Image { get; set; }
    public string ImageUri { get; set; }
    public bool IsRecent { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseYear { get; set; }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to add permission to your project .

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

#### in code behind

```
   List<Dictionary<string, string>> GetPlayList(string rootPath)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> fileList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();



        try
        {
            File rootFolder = new File(rootPath);
            File[] files = rootFolder.ListFiles(); //here you will get NPE if directory doesn't contains  any file,handle it like this.
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.IsDirectory)
                {
                    if (GetPlayList(file.AbsolutePath) != null)
                    {
                        fileList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>(GetPlayList(file.AbsolutePath));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (file.Name.EndsWith(".mp3"))
                {
                    Dictionary<string, string> song = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                    song.Add("file_path", file.AbsolutePath);
                    song.Add("file_name", file.Name);

                    fileList.Add(song);
                }
            }
            return fileList;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And you can invoke it like

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> songList = GetPlayList("/storage/sdcard1/");
```